# React.js/Redux - How to update state if props wasn't changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to update my local state if the props were changed. But I could not find a suitable solution to this problem. `getDerivedStateFromProps` gives me only nextProps and prevState but I need both prevProps and nextProps. Please write any your solution that might solve this problem)

**Situation:** The Cart component (stateful) gets the fetched data from the props and puts that data in `this.state.cart`. The Cart component has `counterHandler` method that triggers whenever the counter is changed (onIcrease, onDecrease, onChange). This handler calculates the data and makes a new data based on the event ( calculating totalPrice and updating the amount of the item ). Then puts the new data into `setState` to update the UI. The state doesn't change because I do this:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
 if (!_.isEqual(nextProps.cart, prevState.cart)) {
   return { cart: nextProps.cart };

 } else return null;
}
```

I do this because I want to update the state when the real data is changed ( the data that comes from the props ).

**Goal:** updating the counter's and the total price's value without making any-side effect ( the values might be updated in the store or only for the local state ).

This is what I mean:

[image: cart]

Comment: you can mirror the props in state object then it's possible to compare old and new prop object in *getDerivedStateFromProps*

Comment: yes, this is nice idea. I'd use this one. thank you kindly man )

Comment: good luck buddy.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) which is called when the props on the component update. It receives `prevProps` and `prevState` as parameters, and you have access to "nextProps" as `this.props`.

For example

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (!_.isEqual(this.props.cart, prevState.cart)) {
   this.setState ({ cart: this.props.cart });
 }
}
```

Comment: sorry, but I cannot really understand you because I want to compare `prevProps` with `nextProps`. but what you wrote is comparing `this.state.props` and `prevState`

Comment: I only used your example, where you're comparing prevProps to prevState, but in my example "this.props" is the "next props" you're looking for

Answer (score -1):

You can use `componentWillReceiveProps` method of react class. This method will be executed when parent component will render, its child will execute `componentWillReceiveProps` method in child. In this method in child you can update state based on new props.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
   //You can access current props via this.props
   //You can access newProps from argument
   //Change component state after comparing both props
}
```

Comment: this method is deprecated.